# using WHERE clause to check if record is receiving different values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I wish to check if a bunch of values in a DB record with a given primary key are different from some user provided values.

One approach is to retrieve the values from the DB and compare them to the user provided values using PHP.

Another approach is to use DB directly to compare the values, and if a record is returned, you know there is an exact match:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t
WHERE pk=123
AND c1=321
AND c2=222
...
AND c8=555
AND c9=434;
```

Is there any pros or cons from using one approach over the other?  Will the DB be smart enough to filter on the pk before the other values?

PS.  Based on this query, if something is changed, I will then do an UPDATE of the new values plus update a date_changed column and a changed_by_user column.  Since I am also updating these last two columns, `PDOStatement::rowCount()` can't be used.  Am I missing something?

Comment: One thing you need to note, is if you're comparing string values with the database, it does them case-insensitively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any pros or cons from using one approach over the other? Will
>   the DB be smart enough to filter on the pk before the other values?

You should definitely do this in your query. The DBMS is smart enough to recognize the pk field in the where clause, in fact it will do query optimization and where clause reordering before processing. This property is by design and the underlying [datastructures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) are designed to work like that.